# How to fix this coloring problem?

Tags: support, code-formatting, design

I have a question that have 5 tags, and c is not one of them. Without c tag, the code block is colorless and harder to read. Other 5 tags are way more important than c tag, therefore I cannot replace any of them with c tag. But I also want the code to be colored. What must I do in this situation?

Comment: The C tag is the most important one; it will get you the most number of views by qualified users.  Drop one of the other tags.

Comment: If it doesn't have a major language tag, hardly anybody will even see your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `<!-- language: c -->` before the code block.

That said, I find it highly unlikely that the other 5 tags are more important.  Having an appropriate language tag is virtually always *the* most important tag for a question, as that's the window through which you'll get the majority of your potential answerers.

Answer (score 3):

Just force the language by adding this before the code block:

```
<!-- language: lang-c -->
```

Remember to have one blank line before that.